# Multi-project setup with Nuget Packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nuget, projects-and-solutions, solution

I have a visual studio solution that has two sub-projects, and these sub-project's use the same nuget packages. I have many years experience with C++ projects, but I am still relatively new to the .net world and nuget packages. I'm trying to achieve the following goals simultaneously.

1. Have my Master solution file in the projects root folder (see directory structure below)
2. Have each sub-project (including the .csproj file) contained in their own sub folders
3. Have only one location that contains a list of all of the packages. I don't like having copies of the same packages.config file in each sub-folder. Would like to have just one at say the Master.sln file level since all of the projects use the same packages and I want to ensure they use the same versions of the same packages.

   - I also noticed that the .csproj files end up containing a copy of what is in the packages.config file. Is there any way to have the packages list be only in one place without copies? Like ONLY in the packages.config file and not in the .csproj file?

Here is my project directory structure

```
{projects root}
    Master.sln
    packages.config {is it possible for this file to be at this level}
    Proj1
        Proj1.sln {do not want solution at this level}
        Proj1.csproj
        Program.cs
        packages.config {do not want at this level}
    Proj2
        Proj2.sln {do not want solution at this level}
        Proj2.csproj
        Program.cs
        packages.config {do not want at this level}
```

At the moment, if I compile either of the Proj1.sln or Proj2.sln files in VisualStudio the "packages" folder is created and the project compile correctly. However if I open the Master.sln (which contains the two sub projects) and compile, then the "packages" folder is created at the same level as the Master.sln file, but the projects don't build, I'm assuming because they can't find the packages.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: "I want to ensure they use the same versions of the same packages" That's what the `Consolidate` tab is for in the Package Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

> Multi-project setup with Nuget Packages

I am afraid you have to copy of the same packages.config file in each sub-folder, that because **NuGet team deprecated solution level packages in NuGet 3.0**:

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/522

And the default nuget version for Visual Studio 2017 is **4.0** and above.

So, you could not have just one packages.config at say the `Master.sln` file level.